# confusion about github branch creation

Tags: git, github

New to github and using github tool for window.I have cloned [original repository](https://github.com/shopizer-ecommerce/shopizer) from `github` to my local repository.

I was trying to create a new branch so as I can push changes to this new branch but seems like everything is going to [forked version](https://github.com/umeshawasthi/shopizer).

Do I need to follow some other steps so as this newley created branch can be pushed to main repository or I need to create a pull request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd need to create a pull request on the original repository if it's not controlled by you.

Comment: I am added as a contributor but yes I am not owner of this repository.Do I need to create a pull request for this?

Answer (score 0):

In cases when you don't own the repository, you need to fork it first then push to forked version and then create a pull request, original would definitely won't want to add code from someone he doesn't know.

Answer (score 0):

If you are a contributor, you should be able to just clone the original repository. You don't need to fork it.

First

`git clone git@github.com:shopizer-ecommerce/shopizer.git`

You can then create a local branch:

`git checkout -b my-branch`

Make changes, commit to local branch and push it to origin.

`git push origin my-branch`

Then using github interface you create new pull request with master and your new branch.

Hope that helps somehow.